# conda update anaconda gives "The following packages will be DOWNGRADED due to dependency conflicts"

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I was told a while ago to regularly run `conda update conda` and then `conda update anaconda` in order to keep everything python related up to date.

Today I ran `python -V` and got `Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)`

Then when I ran `conda update conda`, I got: `All requested packages already installed.`

`conda                     4.1.11                   py27_0`

However, when I ran `conda update anacond`, I got a whole list of pacakges to be DOWNLOADED, packages to be INSTALLED, packages to be UPDATED, and **"packages to be DOWNGRADED due to dependency conflicts"**

I proceeded (cause why not...), and when I ran `python -V` afterwards, I got: `Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)`, so **both python and Anaconda have been downgraded, Anaconda significantly so**.

Is this normal or desirable to keep everything consistent? Is there a way to avoid it? Is it really the best thing to run `conda update conda` and then `conda update anaconda` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly do the same thing and everything is fine till yesterday, when I got the same thing when updating, I don't think it's normal and I think it may have something to do with the new release version.

I tried to re update and it didn't work. I try to force the update by using:

```
conda install anaconda=4.1.1
```

But it showed me that the spyder-app has conflicts. Maybe that coul help in your case.

My temporary solution till the conflict is solve, was to run:

```
conda update --all
```

which creates a custom version of anaconda with all the packages updated. I will try to update anaconda later and see if I could install the newest version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped. Please let me know if you manage to install the newest version.